# What's the use of HMAC in PBKDF2?

Tags: hash, hmac, pbkdf-2

As far as I know, PBKDF2 uses an underlying pseudorandom function in order to generate a hash (like SHA256) so as far I understood PBKDF2 is basically a hash function that uses an underlying function in order to generate a hash but what I don't understand is that what's the point of hmac here?

I expected to use something like PBKDF2WithSHA512 instead of PBKDF2WithHmacSHA512 and I really can't understand what's the point of HMAC.

Comment: I think these answers to this question [What's the difference between PBKDF and SHA and why to use them together?](https://crypto.stackexchange.com/q/35275/18298) might enlighten you.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [What's the difference between PBKDF and SHA and why use them together?](https://crypto.stackexchange.com/questions/35275/whats-the-difference-between-pbkdf-and-sha-and-why-use-them-together)